# Watir/Watij integrating into Robot Framework?

Tags: watir, robotframework, watij

I'm evaluating different tools for WebApp testing. Is anyone knowing if Watir or Watij can be integrated into the Robot Framework or as a workaround Watir/Watij can be started from command line which can be implemented into Robot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [water-robot](https://github.com/semperos/watir-robot/#readme) library listed on robotframework.org.